# Does the folder I am in have any significance in git?

Tags: git, directory, branch, git-checkout

I am git newbie. Learning while doing things.
I have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15030975/git-separate-folder-for-each-branch-setting-it-up) setup. Now lets say I am on `branch1` folder (git bash), like `c:\branch1\` and do a `checkout master`. It switches to `master` branch, but does not change the folder. So the folder I am in is not the `master's` folder, which is lets say `c:\master\`. Its `branch1`s folder.

Do I need to switch to `master's` folder to do any work on `master` branch files? Or just checkout is enough.

May be its a dumb question. :-) But I am trying to understand this. So want to get it clear.

Comment: Branches and folders have _nothing_ to do with eachother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has already been noted, branches have **nothing to do** with folders. A branch with git is one of a few ways to say "a version of the code"

For example when you

```
git checkout master
```

you are telling git

> show me the `master` version of the code

likewise

```
git checkout branch1
```

is telling

> show me the `branch1` version of the code

When you `git checkout` it will dump the appropriate files and folders into your working directory, that is the folder containing the `.git` folder. The `.git` folder might be hidden depending on your system, but be aware of it.